# Creation of Azure Databricks Mount Points using Terraform

Tags: terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-databricks

I would like to know if there is anyway i can create Azure Databricks mount points using the Azure Databricks Resource Provider. Various Azure Service Principals are used to give access to various mount points in ADLS Gen2.
So can these mount points be put inside Databricks with the right Service Principal access, can this be done using Terraform or what is the best way to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with the `azurerm` provider as it works only with the Azure-related objects, and DBFS mount is specific for Databricks. But [Databricks Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/1.6.5/docs) has [databricks_mount](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/mount) resource that is designed for that task.  Just take into account that because there is no such thing as "mount API", mounting is performed by spinning off a small cluster, and performing `dbutils.fs.mount` command inside it.

P.S. Mounts are really not recommended anymore due the fact that all users of the workspace will have access to the mount's content using the permissions of the service principal that was used for mounting.